# flask-sqlacodegen suports python 3.4?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlacodegen

I am trying to generate a flask-sqlalchemy for an existing mysql db.
I used the following command
flask-sqlacodegen --outfile rcdb.py mysql://username:password@hostname/tablename

The project uses python 3.4. Any clues?

```Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/devaccess/py_api/ds/venv/bin/flask-sqlacodegen", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/var/www/devaccess/py_api/ds/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlacodegen/main.py", line 59, in main

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/devaccess/py_api/ds/venv/bin/flask-sqlacodegen", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/var/www/devaccess/py_api/ds/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlacodegen/main.py", line 59, in main
args.flask, ignore_cols, args.noclasses)
File "/var/www/devaccess/py_api/ds/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlacodegen/codegen.py", line 606, in init
model = ModelClass(table, links[table.name], inflect_engine, not nojoined)
File "/var/www/devaccess/py_api/ds/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlacodegen/codegen.py", line 335, in init
relationship_ = ManyToManyRelationship(self.name, target_cls, association_table, inflect_engine)
File "/var/www/devaccess/py_api/ds/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlacodegen/codegen.py", line 501, in init
self.kwargs['secondary'] = repr(assocation_table.schema + '.' + assocation_table.name)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

try specifying your database schema with option --schema